# Finding number of occurrences on website

Tags: java

I'm making a program that can search a website for a targeted word. I've been able to make it load the site, however i don't know how to make the method searchHits find and count its target. Help would be appreciated.

```
public String[] searchHits(String target){
        String[] out = new String[0];
            }

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String AFTEN = "https://theguardian.com/";
    String TARGET = "and";
```

I've also tried this without much luck:

```
 public int searchHits(String target, String aften){ 
    String[] out = new String[0];
    int occurrences = 0;

    if (aften.contains(target)) {
       occurrences++;
    }
    return occurrences;
    }
```

Comment: What are you using to read from the website?

Comment: I've created a method that crawls on the site, using Jsoup

Comment: I've tried this, but it doesn't work.

 public int searchHits(String target, String aften){ 
        String[] out = new String[0];
        int occurrences = 0;

  if (aften.contains(target)) {
           occurrences++;
        }
        return occurrences;
        }

Comment: can you post that code, as well?

Comment: where is your loop? You have to implement a loop somewhere to iterate the data you are evaluating.

Answer (score 0):

Hum... When looking for strings into an input text, you have to take care of these matters:

1. If the target string has to be matched literally, or shall be matched no matter upper or lowercase or some other idiomatic symbols (accent marks, etc).
2. If the target string is complete, or might be a part of a word.

In the first case, you have to pre-process first the input text and convert it to lowercase, and (depending on the target language) even taking out the accent marks and convert it to plain, lowercase text. And so the target text.

In the second case (complete words), you'll have also to tokenize first the input text into individual *words*, separating by commas, periods, colons, semicolons, etc. And also the target string. And then, iterate the full list of words looking for the target words.

If you want a simple approach, you should, at least, compare the text in a case-insensitive way. For this matter, you could use [String.regionMatches](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#regionMatches%28boolean,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29) instead of `contains`.