# Make web crawler parse through websites

Tags: java, html

So earlier today i posted 
[Finding number of occurrences on website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33639413/finding-number-of-occurrences-on-website)

But the answer i received did not help as much as i hoped it would. I'm trying to tell a crawler to read through the text from the websites it finds and search for one given word. I found out about this:

```
 org.jsoup.nodes.Document dom = Jsoup.parse(html);
```

However I have no idea how to implement it. Please help

Crawler

```
public void crawlFrom(String link){ // TODO

    try
    {
        Connection connection = Jsoup.connect(link).userAgent(USER_AGENT);
        Document htmlDocument = connection.get();
        this.htmlDocument = htmlDocument;
        System.out.println("Received web page at " + link);

        Elements linksOnPage = htmlDocument.select("a[href]");
        System.out.println("------------------\nFound (" + linksOnPage.size() + ") links\n------------------");

        for(Element newLink : linksOnPage)
        {
            this.linkListe.add(newLink.absUrl("href"));

        }
    }
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        // We were not successful in our HTTP request
        System.out.println("Error in out HTTP request " + ioe);
    }
       System.out.println(linkListe);
    return;
}
```

Searcher

```
public int searchHits(String target, String aften){ // TODO
    String[] out = new String[0];
    int occurrences = 0;

    if (aften.contains(target)) {
       occurrences++;
    }
    return occurrences;
    }
```

Comment: "_However I have no idea how to implement it_" is not a specific programming question. If you need to learn how to use the tool, google for jsoup.

Comment: I am, but I'm not as good with Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what `aften` and `target` is, but I will give you a snippet of code that searches for occurrences of a word in a text.

```
public int searchHits(String target, String aften){ // TODO

    int index = 0;
    int occurrences = 0;

    while(index != -1){

        index = aften.indexOf(target,index); // start search from index 0

        if(index != -1){
            occurrences ++; //if found, increment the counter
            index += target.length(); // set the next starting index to be after this current index
        }
    }
    return occurrences;
}
```

---------------------UPDATE---------------------

Change your abstract method from `int searchHits(String word);` to `int searchHits(String target, String aften);`

Comment: aften is the webpage, target is the word

Comment: The program crashes, unfortunately

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The type MyEngine must implement the inherited abstract method SearchEngine.searchHits(String)

 at Innlevering2_algoritmer.MyEngine.searchHits(MyEngine.java:15)
 at Innlevering2_algoritmer.MyEngine.main(MyEngine.java:124)

Comment: Here's the abstract method 
 int searchHits(String word);

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Innlevering2_algoritmer.MyEngine.main(MyEngine.java:123)

Comment: This has become a very different question now. You need to include the code that causes the error in the main question

Comment: You asked a question about word searching, and so I gave you a solution for that problem.
And now you are asking about a different kind of error, which should be in a seperate question :)

Comment: So if my answer solved your word search problem, please kindly accept it as an answer, and post your current problem (NullPointerException) as a seperate question :)